# How to concatenation href value

Tags: asp-classic

I have got **asp classic page** and i need to show link with some value on the page.

Here is the link and i need to attach strEmpcode with the address.

strEmpcode = session("empcode")

```
 <td><li>
    <a href="http://192.1.1.1:85/reports.aspx?empcode= & strEmpcode"> Report</a>
 <td><li>
```

So on click it should pass the address in this form:

```
http://192.1.1.1:85/reports.aspx?empcode=123
```

**I need to show it on design time (inline page) not on runtime.**

How can i fix it?

Comment: Remove C# tag, please.  How are you getting your strEmpcode?  If from a database, then the value will need to be written to the page in runtime.  Otherwise, you'll need to use JavaScript on the client-side to generate your link.

Comment: Also, what language are you using for the class ASP page?  VBScript or JavaScript?

Comment: strEmpcode = session("empcode")

Comment: lboshuizen's answer is correct, and for the record, it is runtime.  This value would not be written during design time.

Comment: i am a .net developer and has no experience in asp classic side and page was written in inline format.

Comment: Classic ASP is a completely different technology to ASP.NET. ASP.NET can be inline or have code-behind files. Classic ASP is always inline.  You say "I have got asp classic page" - I think you actually have an ASP.NET page written in the inline style. Can you confirm, and I'll edit the post and comments to clean this up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<a href='http://192.1.1.1:85/reports.aspx?empcode=<%=strEmpcode %>'> Report</a>
```

Just to concatenate strEmpcode to the URL. Where that var gets a value is not clear from your question now...

Comment: If OP is generating strEmpcode on the server-side, then this is correct.  At the moment, I think that it's unclear, since they are saying "not on runtime".

Comment: The solution will actually work in both Classic ASP or ASP.NET, which is handy!

Answer (score -2):

You can concatenate directly in the server side code

EDIT:
You can still build a concatenate string in the ASP server side code.

```
<%
   var mylink = "..." + "..."
 %>


<a href="<%=mylink %>" />
```

Comment: I need to show it on design time (inline page) not on runtime.

Comment: Design time? No such thing in Classic ASP. Do you really mean ASP.NET after all? If so, please edit your question...