# asp.net - Create contatenated href tag in a repeater element

Tags: html, asp.net, href, repeater

I have a repeater on my asp.net page, bound to a datareader in code-behind. I'd like to turn one of the repeater elements into the href of an anchor tag. The repeater element is the name of a file, and I want my user to be able to click on the tag to download the file.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802693/how-to-concatenation-href-value) got me pretty close; my repeater element looks like this:

```
<%#Eval("DocumentName")%>
```

And my anchor looks like this:

```
<a href= "docs/?<%#Eval("DocumentName")%>"><%#Eval("DocumentName")%></a>
```

This opens the docs subfolder in a directory listing of the entire docs folder. I want the 'Open/Save File' dialog to open when my user clicks the href, not go to a separate page that lists the files in the docs directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of linking to a page that lists the files, link to the actual document. If the documents are static files in the docs folder, and DocumentName is the file name, then removing the question mark from your link should do the trick.

```
<a href="docs/<%#Eval("DocumentName")%>"><%#Eval("DocumentName")%></a>
```

Note, I also removed a space after `href=` in your link. Not sure if that was a typo in your question or not.

Comment: Worked like a charm, mason. I didn't really understand what the question mark was doing. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Stanton Usually the question mark in a URL denote a "query string", a sequence of key/value pairs that are passed to the server, that the server will use to determine how to process the request. For example, `Products.aspx?id=5` will probably display the product with an ID of 5, while `FileRetriever.ashx?FileName=MyFile.pdf` would probably cause a file with a Filename of `MyFile.pdf` to be retrieved from a database and written to the client.

Comment: Got it, I've just been reading up. So in my case, the pair I was passing was the page and the filename. I learned something today, thanks again.